In what countries do the police have a duty to protect people?
The Supreme Court of the United States infamously ruled in the 2005 case Castle Rock v. Gonzalez that the police have no duty to protect the public, a ruling that was condemned internationally. Are there any countries that do legally mandate such a duty for the police?

FWIW: That's definitely not what SCOTUS said in Castle Rock. The holding was only that the Fourth Amendment does not give citizens a "property interest" in police enforcement of a protection order. In many other situations, American police definitely do have a duty to protect people, but under different laws.

The police roles and responsibilities are governed by state law (example California law for the situation). I don't think the SCOTUS ruled what you say.

Almost all civil law countries recognize an affirmative duty of law enforcement and prosecutors to enforce the law.

@littleadv Actually, this is very close to what SCOTUS held. Police have no duty to enforce that law that is enforceable in a civil action and there is no cause of action under § 1983 for the failure of law enforcement to act (absent special circumstances like a person in their custody).

@bdb484 The are only a few situations when policy have a duty to protect people in U.S. law. There are rare and isolated exceptions but that's the general rule.

@ohwilleke I don't think I can agree. I think it's more accurate to say that police almost always have a duty to protect people. The problem is that the duty (1) most frequently derives from criminal law, policing regulations, or departmental policy, rather than the Constitution; and (2) therefore is enforceable by prosecutors or oversight bodies or supervisors, but not by the public.

@bdb484 There is almost never a criminal duty to do so (except against fellow cops or when someone is in the custody of the cop), and almost never a legally enforceable civil duty to do so. It is certainly grounds for termination of employment by officer's employer and would constitute good cause in that context. Cops are fired for not enforcing the law vigorously enough all time time. But this is in the same category of things as not showing up to work, or showing insubordination to your superior officer, or not filing reports in a timely fashion.

It sounds like we agree: Police usually have a duty to protect the public, and the public usually cannot enforce that duty.

Or, rather, the public can enforce that duty through civil administration, not courts.
